# Laravel 5.5 Many-to-Many relationship with a One-to-Many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I am working on a project where an account can only have one primary user but multiple regular users. I am trying to determine how to differentiate the users. Here is what I currently have setup:

**USER MODEL RELATIONSHIPS**

```
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Account', 'account_user');
}
```

**ACCOUNT MODEL RELATIONSHIPS**

Primary Account User (One-to-Many)

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\User::class);
}
```

Regular Account Users (Many-to-Many)

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'account_user');
}
```

In the page where these users are going to be displayed I am not sure how to split up the users (The primary user from the regular users). Below is my migrations for the tables.

**USERS TABLE**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**ACCOUNTS TABLE**

```
Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('account_number');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**ACCOUNT USER (PIVOT TABLE)**

```
Schema::create('account_user', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->integer('account_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('accounts')->onDelete('cascade');

});
```

I really just don't understand 
1. How to tell the two apart Primary User from Regular User. 
2. Where to create the function above (model, in the view, service, ...).

Thanks for the help and please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure of your question but I will attempt to respond to it. I also hope it is not late already
The primary user of an account can be gotten by:

```
Account::find($account)->user; //primary user
```

The regular users can be gotten by doing

```
Account::find($account)->users; //regular users
```

$account been the id of the account you are looking for it's primary user and regular users